# Jenkins hangs after running jar file

Tags: java, batch-file, jenkins, jar, agent

I am trying to execute a jar file via Jenkins on a slave node.
After the jar is executed, jenkins hangs and does not stop running.
My jar is on a windows machine, the slave node is started as Java Web Start agent.

[image]

Comment: We need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: i've created a jenkins free project. for the compiling i used a windows batch command:
"java -jar myjar-with-dependencies.jar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `System.exit(0);` and it seems to be working.